# woocommerce variant choose by programming/css

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, variant

I have online store based on `woocommerce` plugin, every product have 8-11 variants(phone models compatibility).

How to provide the option to choose which variant will display depends on user preference (or certain pages will display another variant than the default)?

Comment: Have you checked woocommerce [docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/) for creating variable product? That is exactly what you need

Comment: maybe i didnt explained myself

Comment: i already have 100 products, each of them 8-10 variants. 
i want customer who says i need vaiant X. to see my website only the products how have this variant!